# If $A$ commutes with $A^{\ast}A$ then is $A$ normal?

Tags: matrices

For any square matrix $A$, if $A$ commutes with $A^{\ast}A$ then is $A$ normal? I solved for $2 \times 2$ matrices and it is true that $A$ is normal. For other order I can't prove or can't find counter example.

Comment: Is $A$ invertible?

Comment: The question is for any matrix.

Comment: @daw you assumed, without loss of generality, that $A$ is upper triangular and $A^*A$ diagonal.  Perhaps it is useful, then, to note that the off-diagonal entries of $A^*A$ are dot-products of columns from $A$.

Comment: @daw another bit to notice is that if $A^*A$ is diagonal with no repeated eigenvalues, then $A^*A$ commutes only with other diagonal matrices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes.

We begin by noting that
$$
(AA^*)A = A(A^*A) = (A^*A)A
$$
Thus, for every vector $x$, we have $(A^*A)(Ax) = (AA^*)(Ax)$.  That is, for every vector $y$ in the image of $A$, we have $AA^* y = A^*Ay$.  Note, however, that
$$
\ker(AA^*) = \ker(A^*) = im(A)^\perp
$$
So we may conclude from the above that $im(A^*A) \subseteq im(AA^*) = im(A)$.  In fact, since these matrices have the same rank, we have $im(A^*A) = im(AA^*)$.  Since these matrices are self-adjoint, we also have $\ker(A^*A) = \ker(AA^*)$.

Thus, $AA^*$ and $A^*A$ have the same kernel $K$, and they are the same transformation over $K^\perp$.  It follows that $AA^* = A^*A$, as desired.

Comment: Where do you get $im(A^*A)\subset im(AA^*)$ from?

Comment: Every element of $im(A^*A)$ has the form $A^*Ay$ for some $y\in \ker(A^*A)^\perp$.

Comment: This seems trivial. But where does $AA^*$ come into play? Did you mix up the order of $A$ and $A^*$ in the comment?

Comment: Sorry, that should be $AA^*$ in the above instead. Yes, I mixed the order

Comment: I still can't figure out how $im(A^{\ast}A) \subset im(AA^{\ast})$. Also, is it a result that if two self adjoint matrices have same kernel then they are equal? How did you get the second part of the proof?

Comment: $$
im(AA^*) = AA^*(\Bbb C^n) = AA^*(im(A)^\perp) = A^*A(im(A)^\perp) \subseteq A^*A(\Bbb C^n)
$$

Comment: @Hemant the self-adjoint matrices have the same kernel **and** they are the same transformation over its orthogonal complement.